# VBA JSON Out of Stack Space

Tags: json, vba, excel, class

Running one Sub in a Module.  Using VBA-JSON.  Am trying to link the JSON fields with a custom class in VBA, It works for about 7 of the items, but when I get to the 8th, I get an error

> Out of Stack Space

Here is the code:

```vb
Sub XXX()

    Dim http As Object
    Dim Json As Object
    Dim sql As String

    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Set clsCl = New clsClient
    sql = "{""cid"": 2028, ""data"": ""client""}"
    http.Open "POST", "https://localhost/xxx.php", False
    http.Send sql

    Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(http.ResponseText)
    clsCl.caseid = Json("caseid")
    clsCl.fname = Json("fname")
    clsCl.lname = Json("lname")
    clsCl.isssn = Json("isssn")
    clsCl.isdob = Json("isdob")
    clsCl.isage = Json("isage")
    clsCl.issex = Json("issex")
    clsCl.facility = Json("snfdr")

End Sub
```

`http.ResponseText` content is as follows:

```
{
    "fname": "George",
    "lname": "Jungle",
    "isdob": "0000-00-00",
    "isage": "0",
    "isssn": "2/2/1932",
    "facility": "HIDDENHILLSMANOR",
    "facilityadmitdate": "0000-00-00",
    "issex": "Male",
    "snfdr": "240.00",
    "csfname": "Jane",
    "cslname": "Jungle",
    "csssn": "234-56-7890",
    "csdob": "1937-06-06",
    "csage": "80",
    "cssex": "Female",
    "csaddress": "1212GrapevilleHillRoad",
    "cscsz": "Sarver, PA16000",
    "cstelephone": ""
}
```

Comment: What does the response look like?  You can obfuscate any sensitive info, but it would be useful to include it here.

Comment: {
   "fname": George",
   "lname": "Jungle",
  "isdob": "0000-00-00",
  "isage": "0",
  "isssn": "2/2/1932",
  "facility": "HIDDEN HILLS MANOR",
  "facilityadmitdate": "0000-00-00",
  "issex": "Male",
  "snfdr": "240.00",
  "csfname": "Jane",
  "cslname": "Jungle",
  "csssn": "234-56-7890",
  "csdob": "1937-06-06",
  "csage": "80",
  "cssex": "Female",
  "csaddress": "1212 Grapeville Hill Road",
  "cscsz": "Sarver, PA  16000",
  "cstelephone": ""
}

Comment: I have no problem parsing that, so maybe the problem is in your clsClient code.

Comment: @user2690440 is there missing doublequote `"fname": George"`?

Comment: Problem was a type in the Class Def.  Thanks Tim.